# How to get the represented character for an encoding in Racket?

Tags: html, unicode, encoding, scheme, racket

From an HTML file I got `&#20351;`. I know it represent the Chinese character `使`. But how to convert them in Racket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `(integer->char 20351)` to get that character, or you can use literal syntax, `#\u4F7F`.